# Unique Key / Idempotency key migration

Tags: postgresql, idempotent

I am using PostgreSQL and I need to migrate Idempotency/unique key from `customer id` to `user id`.

`Customer id` is one to many mapped to `user id`.

Currently the unique index is `customer id + date string`

Further going, I expect no more than one entry in DB per **user** per day, therefore the unique index will be `user id + date string`.

How do I handle such migration without downtime?

Comment: Why are you storing dates as strings?

Comment: It's better to store dates with the `DATE` data type.